# Recursive patching values cutting some data

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm gonna build function which could help me to patch original values.
I will throw example to present idea more clarify.

This is my real object

```
let a = {
    a: 'a',
    b: 'b',
    c: [1,2,3],
    d: {
        e: 'e',
        f: 'f'
    }
};
```

But i want to change `a.d` to `{e: 'e', f: 'ff'}`
Therefore i created function and it partially works. I mean
when i run

```
saveValues({f: 'ff'}, a.d);
```

everything is fine. But this line doesn't work

```
saveValues({d: {f: 'ff'}}, a);
```

Of course it change f to ff, but also deleting e

```
let saveValues = (values: {[key: string]: any}, obj: any) => {
    Object.keys(values).forEach((key: any) => {
        if((obj as Object).hasOwnProperty(key)){
            if(typeof obj[key] == 'object')
            {
                saveValues(values[key], obj[key]);
            }
            obj[key] = values[key];
        }
    })
};
```

Live code: [click](https://agentcooper.github.io/typescript-play/#code/DYUwLgBAhhC8EG8CwAoC7oC4IHIo4BpUMIAjbHUw4jAY2wG0BGAgJgIGYBdItDAE2zI+JdCAohqI0QDMKMnDXQBfVMoDcqVKEgBnKADcQANSjAAriF1wIACgNnLuoQwDWIAJ7ZdYAE4BLADsAcy5sKECPZQIIAHtSACtwyIBKOAA+RCUIAHlEkFowADp3D117RysUoplY3wBRKFoAC1tbUuSPNNhM4VEMfxk2+IToazyEgrBq5qhdHIB3QIAFX1iABxBfMA92zxSUvv7RQdsdzdiZOMS3Ty44eBwRqZwU7OOs6Q+SfSNTCysFQBuluHh41wSoK4KU0X2Oqjh-RGUJsDmBUNhHwR3ww72O2WUbxQGi0KF+Jkq5QQgkQclwMgUymi0BhqFosUCulioCKwFiwVsUFZKCAA)

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(typeof obj[key] == 'object') {
   saveValues(values[key], obj[key]);
 } else {
   obj[key] = values[key];
 }
```

if the value is an object, dont assign it the value but only proceed recursively.

Comment: You only added else, but in my opinion it the same code(hah). I propably have to understand it. Anyway thank you. EDIT: I got it